# Inserção de dados em massa | SPServices | Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint

Tenho uma lista com aproximadamente 1000 registros (nome de pessoas). Tenho também outra lista (agendamento). O que preciso é criar um agendamento dinâmico para cada pessoa da lista, ou seja, o usuário deverá clicar em um botão e o sistema deverá definir uma data e agendar (por exemplo, uma consulta) para cada nome de pessoa da lista.
Consegui fazer o algoritmo para isso, meu problema é com relação a inserção de dados em massa na lista de agendamento, o sistema esta travando.

Existe alguma forma para se resolver este tipo de problema?

Não estou utilizando Web Parts, desenvolvo diretamente em HTML Bootstrap e utilizo a biblioteca SPservices para interagir com o Sharepoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não conheço nada de Sharepoint, mas eu seguiria [essa resposta](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/83539/multiple-inserts-with-spservices-72) e olharia com carinho para esse método [SPServices.SPAddMultipleListItems](http://sympmarc.github.io/SPServices/), que parece promissor.

Note que nos exemplos, onde está &#43; é na verdade o caractere +.

Comment: Darei um olhada @Dudaskank. Valeu pelo retorno.